# Instantiating Python objects, and using lists

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming and trying to teach myself. I'm currently trying to learn how to build objects from classes, which I think I understand. My current task is to add the object into a list and print that list. Ultimately I'm trying to build a program that creates an object and lists each object that has been created in a numbered list, i.e.:

```
1 - tomato, red
2 - corn, yellow
etc...
```

So to begin, I'm just trying to build the basic part of this.
Here is what I made:

```
# Builds objects on instantiation for a vegetable and color
class Veg:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        print('You have created a new', self.color, self.name, end='.\n')

# Function to create a new vegetable and store it in a list
def createVeg():
    name = input('What is the name of the Vegetable? ')
    color = input('What color is the vegetable? ')
    Veg(name, color)
    vegList.append(Veg)
    return

# Initialize variables
vegList = []
choice = 'y'

# Main loop
while choice == 'y':
    print('Your basket contains:\n', vegList)
    choice = input('Would you like to add a new vegetable? (y / n) ')
    if choice == 'y':
        createVeg()
    if choice == 'n':
        break

print('Goodbye!')
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
Your basket contains:
 []
Would you like to add a new vegetable? (y / n) y
What is the name of the Vegetable? tomato
What color is the vegetable? red
You have created a new red tomato.
Your basket contains:
 [<class '__main__.Veg'>]
Would you like to add a new vegetable? (y / n) y
What is the name of the Vegetable? corn
What color is the vegetable? yellow
You have created a new yellow corn.
Your basket contains:
 [<class '__main__.Veg'>, <class '__main__.Veg'>]
Would you like to add a new vegetable? (y / n) n
Goodbye!
```

So, from what I can tell, everything works except for printing the list, which I can not figure out. It seems to be appending the list propery, but not displaying the object. I've also tried a 'for' loop, but got the same result.

Comment: Vegetable shopper RPG - love it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the lines

```
Veg(name, color)
vegList.append(Veg)
```

What you're doing here is creating a new Veg but not assinging anything to it. Then you're appending Veg *the type* to a list. Also, you need to tell Python how to print you `Veg` objects in a human readable way by adding the `__str__` method to your class. Lastly, if you print a list directly (`print vegList`) you'll get the machine readable representation of the contents of the list, which isn't what you want. Iterating over the list's elements and printing them directly will work.

Here's a working version with the requisite changes:

```
# Builds objects on instantiation for a vegetable and color
class Veg:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        print('You have created a new', self.color, self.name, end='.\n')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'One {} {}'.format(self.color, self.name)

# Function to create a new vegetable and store it in a list
def createVeg():
    name = input('What is the name of the Vegetable? ')
    color = input('What color is the vegetable? ')

    vegList.append(Veg(name, color))
    return

# Initialize variables
vegList = []
choice = 'y'

# Main loop
while choice == 'y':
    print('Your basket contains:\n')
    for veg in vegList:
        print(veg)
    choice = input('Would you like to add a new vegetable? (y / n) ')
    if choice == 'y':
        createVeg()
    if choice == 'n':
        break

print('Goodbye!')
```

Answer (score 6):

It is all working as designed. The `<class '__main__.Veg'>` string is the *representation* of your `Veg` class instances.

You can customize that representation by giving your class a [`__repr__` method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

```
class Veg:
    # ....

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Veg({!r}, {!r})'.format(self.name, self.color)
```

All the `__repr__` function has to do is return a suitable string.

With the above example `__repr__` function, your list would instead look like:

```
[Veg('tomato', 'red'), Veg('corn', 'yellow')]
```

You do need to make sure you actually *append* your new instance. Instead of:

```
Veg(name, color)
vegList.append(Veg)
```

do this:

```
newveg = Veg(name, color)
vegList.append(newveg)
```

Comment: I'll have to research this method to understand it. I haven't seen this yet in the book. However, when I plug it in, I get the same result as before.

Comment: Make sure it is part of your `Veg` class. If you are still seeing `<class '__main__.Veg'>` in your results, you didn't add it in the correct location and/or did not reload your code.

Comment: He shouldn't be using `__repr__` for the human readable version of the class; `__str__` is reserved for that. `__repr__` is reserved for the **machine readable** version of the class. See http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__

Comment: @jknupp: But when printing the list, the `repr()` is used automatically. Note that my example creates a reasonable machine representation that could be used to recreate the `Veg` object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right, which is why he shouldn't be printing the list when what he really wants is to print its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
def createVeg():
    name = input('What is the name of the Vegetable? ')
    color = input('What color is the vegetable? ')
    Veg(name, color) # 1
    vegList.append(Veg) # 2
    return
```

The line I've commented as #1 creates a new instance of a veg object. However, it doesn't do anything with it. It doesn't store it anywhere, or name it, like if you had written `a = Veg(name, color)`. Basically, it creates the object, then forgets about it.

The line I've commented as #2 then appends the Veg CLASS to the list, rather than an instance of the class. This would be like adding the concept of an integer to a list, rather than adding an actual integer of 5.

Try replacing these two lines with...

```
v = Veg(name, color)
vegList.append(v)
```

Once you do this, you're still going to want to follow Martijn Pieters' answer to get the object to print correctly.